# Meteor Mup build : FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed

Tags: meteor, mup

I am getting this issue now "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory" and i am unable to pin point what was the issue.

I have used mup deploy in the same project before and used to work without any issue, however, now i am having this issue, and i do remeber i did a meteor upgrade, might that have caused any issue?

Any suggestion or help is much appreciated

Mup version 1.4.4:

Output of command
`

```
bash
▶ mup deploy --verbose
Building App Bundle Locally
   Minifying app code                                                       
<--- Last few GCs --->

[4082:0x23569a0]   273590 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.4 (1578.6) -> 1397.4 (1578.6) MB, 868.8 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[4082:0x23569a0]   274569 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.4 (1578.6) -> 1397.4 (1531.6) MB, 978.7 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[4082:0x23569a0]   275456 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.4 (1531.6) -> 1397.4 (1523.6) MB, 887.4 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x2f94e9f25e91 <JSObject>
    1: /* anonymous */ [/home/sijan/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.2.2.3.tjo788.vwvpr++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:~1748] [pc=0xb955fb1c1e3](this=0x1fa2c9753919 <Parser map = 0x2aac01cbc7f9>,type=0x80a00992c91 <TokenType map = 0x395f5a44a0e1>,pos=0xd8d29a02311 <undefined>)
    2: arguments adapt...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/home/sijan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0.1a0lw5l.27vk++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node]
 2: 0x121809c [/home/sijan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0.1a0lw5l.27vk++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [/home/sijan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0.1a0lw5l.27vk++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/home/sijan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0.1a0lw5l.27vk++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewUninitializedFixedArray(int) [/home/sijan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0.1a0lw5l.27vk++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node]
 6: 0xe1adb3 [/home/sijan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0.1a0lw5l.27vk++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node]
 7: v8::internal::Runtime_GrowArrayElements(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/home/sijan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0.1a0lw5l.27vk++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node]
 8: 0xb955f40463d

=> Build Error. Check the logs printed above.
`
```

Comment: I'm getting this same error intermittently when building 1.6.1.1 meteor bundles. I don't use mup (have a custom deploy instead). As I've never seen it in 1.6.1 think this started with the latest release. We should post this in the meteor forum

Comment: I went ahead and posted this issue in the meteor forum: https://forums.meteor.com/t/heap-out-of-memory-core-dumped-on-1-6-1-1-build/43340